# What does maxmemory flag in Apache Ant java target exactly do?

Tags: java, memory, ant, heap-memory

Take the following `build.xml` snippet:

```xml
  <target name="run">
      <java
        jar="${server-jar}"
        fork="true"
        failonerror="true"
        maxmemory="1g">
          <jvmarg line="${env.JVM_ARGS}"/>
      </java>
  </target>
```

What does the `maxmemory` flag exactly do? Does it set the heap memory initial/max size? I get heap errors and trying to understand if this flag is enough, or I must set `-Xmx` and `-Xms` separately in `JVM_ARGS`.

The documentation of [maxmemory](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) in ant java target is vague to me:

> maxmemory: Max amount of memory to allocate to the forked JVM, ignored if fork is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc for the [`Java` task class](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Java.html#setMaxmemory(java.lang.String)):

> *Corresponds to -mx or -Xmx depending on VM version.*

In the source code, it is referenced [here](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/bd3e69685c5dd83f94c0ee4307d4ad3905089500/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Java.java#L660).

And, yes, [`Xmx`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/java.html) is the setting for the heap:

> Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the heap.

(You may see a bit more info about some of the other Ant `<java>` task settings, too, in the Javadoc.)

Answer (score 1):

`maxmemory` specifies the maximum heap size available to the Java VM.